# Client software c/c++ socket multiple interfaces(bonding?)

Tags: c++, networking, multicast, bsd

Hardware: 1) Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
2) Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
OS : Linux mint Cinnamon  18.3 64-bit(Ubuntu based);Kernel : Linux kernel 4.10.0-38-generic
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609

I did some research about using multiple interfaces in a program. According to one of the most popular guides [https://beej.us/](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/setsockoptman.html) (example field) it must be very easy. But if wired connection is available even after setsocketopt with SO_BINDTODEVICE, socket continues to use wired connection. Does anyone have ideas if it is possible to create a program that uses multiple interfaces? Or that must be two different programs and linux routing commands?

Global purpose is to create a client-server multicast streaming software where on client side load balancing and recovery interface features will be available.

If there any ways of to solve these purposes, will be glad to see.

Comment: In my software that does multicast on all network interfaces, I create one socket per network interface and multiplex the I/O using select().  I find that works better than trying to do handle all of the network devices using only a single socket.  (It does mean your program needs to react when a new interface comes online, by opening a new socket to handle the new interface, and it needs to react when an existing interface goes offline, by closing the socket associated with the now-offline interface)

Comment: I create one socket per network interface. Can you, please, describe it with more details, as I understood  setsocketopt with SO_BINDTODEVICE should do it, but mine doesn't.

Comment: The only setsockopt() that I use is for sending, to make sure the sockets send on the correct interface:  `struct inaddr in; in.s_addr = [...];  setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, &in, sizeof(in))` for IPv4 sockets, and `int scopeID = [...]; setsockopt(fd,  IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_MULTICAST_IF, &scopeID, sizeof(scopeID))` for IPv6 sockets.

For receiving IPv6 multicast packets, be sure to set the sin6_scope_id field of your sockaddr_in6 before passing it to bind().